Showing $S(f;P)-S(f;\tilde{P})\le\omega(f;[a,b])\cdot (\Delta x_{i_1}+\cdots+\Delta x_{i_k})$
Context
The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

Where $S$ and $s$ represents respectively upper and lower Darboux sum, and $\omega$ is the oscillation.
Attempt for the first part
I have successfully showed the left part of inequality for both by:
$$\sigma(f;\tilde{P};\tilde{\xi})-\sigma(f;P;\xi)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}f(\xi_{i,j})\Delta{x_{ij}}-\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}f(\xi_{ij})\Delta{x_{ij}}-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_{ij}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\Delta x_{ij}(f(\xi_{ij})-f(\xi_{i}))$$
If we add $\sup$ to $\sigma(f;P;\xi)$ we get:
$$S(f;\widetilde{P})-S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\Delta x_{ij}(\sup_{\Delta_{ij}} f(\xi_{ij})-\sup_{\Delta_{i}}f(\xi_{i}))$$
Due to the lemma that $A\subset B\implies \sup_A \le \sup_B$
We have that this expression is $\le 0$, which mean the top-left inequality is greater than $0$
And likewise, we could deduce that the bottom-left inequality is greater than $0$
Thoughts for the second part
I had a hard time manipulating $\sup$ and triangle inequalities for this part. I wish somebody can help me with it. I think the $\sigma$ difference expression I got can be used quite effectively.
Editted after 3 hours:
We have $$\sup_{\Delta_{ij}}f(\xi_{ij})-\sup_{\Delta_i}f(\xi_i)\le\sup_{\Delta_i} f(\xi_{ij})-\sup_{\Delta_i} f(\xi_{i})\le \sup_{\Delta_i} (\xi_{ij}-\xi_i)\le \sup_{\Delta_i} |\xi_{ij}-\xi_i|\le \sup_{\xi,\xi'\in [a,b]}|\xi'-\xi|=\omega(f;[a,b])$$
By that, we have:
$$S(f;\widetilde{P})-S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\Delta x_{ij}(\sup_{\Delta_{ij}}f(\xi_{ij})-\sup_{\Delta_{i}}f(\xi_{i}))$$
$$\le \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\Delta{x_{ij}}\omega (f;[a,b])\\ =\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta{x_{i}}\omega(f;[a,b])$$
